# missing method body abstract class

Tags: java, methods, abstract-class

There is an error as 'missing method body or declare abstract' of abstract class. But the class `WaterLevelObserver` is already abstract... how can I  fix this error?

```
abstract class WaterLevelObserver{
    void update(int waterLevel);
}

class SMSWriter extends WaterLevelObserver{
    void update(int waterLevel){
        System.out.println("Sending SMS.. : "+waterLevel);
    }
}

class Alarm extends WaterLevelObserver{
    void update(int waterLevel){
        if(waterLevel>=50){
            System.out.println("ON");
        }else{
            System.out.println("OFF");
        }
    }
}

class Display extends WaterLevelObserver{
    void update(int waterLevel){
        System.out.println("Water level.. : "+waterLevel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a class as `abstract` just means that you can't instantiate it and that you're allowed to define `abstract` methods.

Any method that isn't defined as being `abstract` must have a body. TL;DR - If you don't want to implement `update`, define it as `abstract`:

```
abstract class WaterLevelObserver{
    abstract void update(int waterLevel);
}
```

Comment: IMHO not precise enough: A method declared as not abstract "should" not have a body, it MUST have one!

Comment: @GyroGearless I agree - "must" is a better wording. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Any un-implemented method inside the `abstract` class should also be `abstract`,

so you need to make your method `abstract` and make sure you implement it in your subclass

```
  abstract class WaterLevelObserver{
      abstract void update(int waterLevel);
   }
```

Read the what [**Oracle**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) says.

**See Also :**

- [Should an abstract class have at least one abstract method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283399/should-an-abstract-class-have-at-least-one-abstract-method)

Comment: @xehpuk Any un-implemented methods inside the `abstract` class should be named as abstract rite  ?

Comment: @SanKrish That's right. But abstract classes don't need to have any abstract methods. An example is `java.awt.event.MouseAdapter`. That's also stated in the first sentence of your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to define the body or you have to declare it as `abstract`. If  you dont want to add any body - change

```
 void update(int waterLevel);}
```

to

```
`abstract void update(int waterLevel);}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The method should be abstract too:

```
abstract class WaterLevelObserver
{
    void abstract update(int waterLevel);
}
```

A method that is not declared as `abstract` must be implemented by the class, even if it's in an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

We need to explicitly tell compiler that its a abstract class in the case of abstract class.without the keyword it will search for body. its fine in case of interface as by default all are abstract.

abstract void update(int waterLevel);