# What is the difference in a normal class who has all concrete methods and an abstract class who has all concrete methods

Tags: java, abstract-class

Suppose an abstract class who has all three methods in it and all are concrete methods, compared with a normal class who has all three methods which are also concrete.

What is the difference between them in an application, because they are now basically serving the same purpose. Why this is permissible?

Take an abstract class, let's say:

```
abstract class A {
    public void open() {} 
    public void close() {} 
    public void pull() {}
}
```

And a normal class:

```
class A {
    public void open() {} 
    public void close() {} 
    public void pull() {}
}
```

What's the difference between them, because if we remove the `abstract` keyword then both are same.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: The primary difference is that an abstract class cannot be instantiated. If there are no abstract members, that's the only (important) difference. Plus, an abstract class cannot be declared final.

Comment: You can not initialize `abstract` class. In your case, the meaning of an abstract class is lost.

Comment: Is your question different from this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362446/abstract-class-with-all-concrete-methods?rq=1

Comment: Abstract class means it is abstract not complete. It needs another class to complete its functionalities.

Comment: But i still dont understand what is the need of this ?why this is permissible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an abstract class. One difference is an how you instantiate them:

```
A a = new A(); // for normal class
A a = new A(){}; // for abstract class with no abstract with no abstract memebers
```

The second line creates an instance of an *annonynous* sublass of A.

Answer (score 1):

A concrete class can be instantiated but an abstract class can't no matter what. The compiler doesn't care about whether the class has abstract members or not. An abstract class just can't be instantiated! When you instantiate an abstract class with no abstract members with an anonymous inner class, you don't need anything in the curly braces. That is because all the methods are implemented. I guess this counts as another difference.

Answer (score 0):

Though @Bohemian is right, an `abstract` class also, when `extend`ed, all `abstract` methods within the `abstract` class MUST be implemented into the class which is `extend`ing our `abstract` class. For example, this does NOT work.

**MyClass**:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractClass {

}
```

**AbstractClass**:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract void test();
}
```

`MyClass` must contain all methods in the `AbstractClass` class. Also, all `abstract` methods cannot have a body.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking about this you know. He/she asks about **difference between a normal class who has all concrete methods and _an abstract class who has all concrete methods_**